# Include System Library with qmake on osx

Tags: c++, macos, shared-libraries, qmake

i have a working cmake project that i need to move to qmake.

Everything is working but the include of a library called octomap.

I installed ( sudo make install ) octomap  in system

```
/usr/local/lib/liboctomap.a
/usr/local/lib/liboctomap.dylib
```

and the headers in

```
/usr/local/lib/include/octomap/
```

Lets say project is so composed:

foo.h

```
...
#include <octomap/OcTree.h>
octomap::OcTree tree(0.1);
...
```

foo.cpp

```
...
#include <octomap/OcTree.h>
using namespace octree;
tree.doSomething();
...
```

foo.pro

```
...
unix|win32: LIBS += -loctomap
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/
...
```

Compiling results in a **error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64** due to

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "octomap::OcTreeNode::createChild(unsigned int)", referenced from:
    octomap::OccupancyOcTreeBase<octomap::OcTreeNode>::updateNodeRe...[a very long stack]
```

That should means that octomap library has not be linked, and i tried also adding it in the project, using pkgconfig and using an absolute path. They all result in same error, while if i use it in a cmake project it works fine.

Comment: You need to set the library path where to search for the library as well.

Comment: yes i forgot to say i also tried with 
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -loctomap 
and it didnt work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a missing library, i also had to include the octomath lib

```
unix|win32: LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ -loctomap
unix|win32: LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ -loctomath
```

hope can be useful to someone.

Comment: That is not quite inline with your question. Have you missed mentioning something?

Comment: That's all i knew :/ i know it's weird otherwise i'd have solved without asking :/ i may delete the question but i don't know if worst.
The missing library was required by the library i added, i can just say this, i didnt notice the missing symbol was not in the interface of octomap, but in the octomath ( that i didnt need directly ).

Comment: Strange, but do not worry. :)